# Anonymous arrays in C++

Tags: c++

In C99+ I can use anonymous arrays and structs as compound literals, e.g.

```
void f(unsigned char *data);

f((char []){ 42, 15, 33 });
```

that is equivalently

```
{
    char tmp[] = { 42, 15, 33 };
    f(tmp);
}
```

Are there ways to do similar things in C++?

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 you have [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) which allows something similar:

```
// Declare function
void f(std::initializer_list<int> data);

...

// Call function
f({ 1, 2, 3, 4 });
```

Most [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) have been modified to take `std::initializer_list`, so you can have e.g. a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead:

```
// Function declaration, call as before
void f(const std::vector<int>& data);
```